# custom table with sort feature, on click of each column

Tags: reactjs

I was building a custom table component, here i am able to find the elements, but i am little confused on this sort, so i am able to sort it but sometimes the sort doesn't work properly,

i clicked on first column two times it sorted, now on next column i click it doesn't works in the initial case but from second time its working

also this width is not properly working tried giving auto but when search input comes its increasing

Main snippet where i handle the sort.

```
 const handleSort = (columnKey, direction) => {
    let sortableItems = [...tableData];
    sortableItems.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a[columnKey] < b[columnKey]) {
        return direction === "ASC" ? -1 : 1;
      }

      if (a[columnKey] > b[columnKey]) {
        return direction === "ASC" ? 1 : -1;
      }
      return 0;
    });
    dispatch({ tableData: sortableItems });
    if (sortDirection === "ASC") {
      return dispatch({ sortDirection: "DESC" });
    }
    dispatch({ sortDirection: "ASC" });
  };
```

For better understanding what i have tried -  working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-jennings-09hgl) link here.

Also is there a better way to do this reusable component, confused on this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no mistake on sorting part, it just so happens when you do the case that you said above, click two time on first column and than first time on the Age does not work, its because clicking two times you sorted items in a way that clicking first time on Age will do the same thing.

Here is a fork of your codesandbox that i modified with separated sort columns: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-smoke-mwh4s

As for the width, that is a strange thing happening. I would suggest that you use css grid since it is way more reliable than tables.

Also i noticed a problem in your code in Table:169. You are using `rowItem.key` which is undefined since that is a key of the object `rowRecord`. Here is the solution.

```js
<tr key="{rowRecord.key}">
  {Object.keys(rowRecord).map(rowItem => { 
     if (rowItem === "key") return null;

     return <td key="{rowRecord.key}">{rowRecord[rowItem]}</td>
  ; })}
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks Mario for the quick response, but how can i solve that sort feature, since i am using a single sort direction so it uses the same variable how should i approach the other way

Comment: Where you able to see the codesandbox ? what i have tried so far

Comment: Yes, that is where i saw the problem with `key`. As for the sorting, you can just have that `sortingDirection` be object with two values, one for name and one for age sorting direction.

Comment: Also, you should give your `columns` one more property for name and age, the key in the object `sortingDirection` that it will use to know what is the direction.

Comment: one sample codesandbox, i was checking this one and trying it to do https://codesandbox.io/s/iozjk , this a library called antd, but is there any way how to achieve this in mine question this default and all, if you see here click on both columns you will be able to see it, i am confused how to have this on each column

Comment: Sorry mario, didn't understood, can you guide me in here , i think there is fork option https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-jennings-09hgl

Comment: I will come back to you later and write you what i meant, up there in the codesandbox and make a fork of it, with object properties.

Comment: Okay are u able to see the other codesandbox where I mentioned in the comment. Sure will wait for your reply I will try mean while

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/iozjk - this feature that i was looking, what i have tried https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-jennings-09hgl

Comment: @ Mario tried but no luck, made the code as the same in the question

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS hey man, here is my fork: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-smoke-mwh4s i added different sort keys so that you dont mix name and age and also the one that is active has better visibility. I will modify my answer so that it has link to this fork. See if it works and leave a comment here so i can make changes if needed

Comment: @ Mario, thanks for the response i have checked the codesandbox which you have done the changes, https://codesandbox.io/s/iozjk but if u see this , this part is not adding any ascend or descend inside the table component, i was looking in the same way so i can give a function who consumes this component on sort, can you check this one https://codesandbox.io/s/iozjk, is it possible to do it in mine

Comment: if you check the antd table it takes the sort direction from not a common one, it has its own one, how should i approach this one

Comment: I see that antd has its object that you pass. What is the question here? Do you want to create similar system like antd where you pass function?

Comment: yes, where it will have a default if no functions are passed else it will have the custom function, i am trying also , also the current handle search does internally can i make a function which can be passed

Comment: Ok, i understand. Well, since you are using reducer for managing data, you should move your sorting logic from Table component to parent component. So same as antd, you pass functions with dispatch and handle data from Table component. Instead of calling dispatch from your Table component, you pass it as function as you said.

Comment: If i have time i will take look at my fork of your code and put some work in it

Comment: I think i figured out a way, will post in a time, need to test it :) Thanks Mario

Comment: @ Mario i have done it 95% but small issues and doubts are there, let me know if you have some time so i will create a codesandbox